# Operation is not valid due to the state of the object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, webclient

When making multiple requests in quick succession, I am sometimes hit with an InvalidOperationException which is marked as the operation is not valid due to the state of the object. I'm not entirely sure what's wrong  with the following code:

```
   this.Abort();

        this.request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        this.result = new WebClientAsyncResult(this.request);

        if (data != null)
        {
            this.request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            this.request.Method = "POST";
        }

        // BeginGetResponse does have a synchronous component
        // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx
        Action asyncAction = () =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.request == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Request is null");
                    return;
                }

                if (request.Method == "POST")
                {
                    GetRequest(result, data, responseAction, errorAction);
                }
                else
                {
                    GetResponse(result, responseAction, errorAction);
                }
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Invalid");
                if (this.request == null)
                {
                    errorAction(new Error(ex.InnerException) {WasAborted = true});
                }
            }
        };

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(asyncAction, null, null);

        return this.result;
```

Comment: Looks like it is something to do with aborting a request before making one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solve by using a local variable outside of the lambda as it wasn't capturing the value of the field until execution which was causing issues.